# C# RegisterPostBackControl does not work with Timer in another update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, timer, postback

In my application I am using asp:GridView with download file link for each row. In order to register postback control I am using OnRowDataBound attribute of GridView.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
...
    <asp:GridView ID="folderContentGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="bindDownloadAction">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center" HeaderStyle-Width="6%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <ul class="icons-list hide-if-no-action">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-menu9"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left fl-drp">
                                <li id="liDownloadBtn" runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("FileType").ToString().Equals("File")%>'>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownloadBtn" CssClass="block-ui-click" runat="server" data-pid ='<%# Eval("UiIndex") %>' 
                                    OnClick="onClickDownloadBtn"><i class="icon-download"></i>Download</asp:LinkButton></li>
                                <li id="liDeleteFileBtn" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeleteFileBtn" runat="server" data-pid ='<%# Eval("UiIndex") %>' data-md-button="btnDeleteFileHdn" 
                                    data-md-action="DELETE" data-md-title="Delete File" data-md-message="Do you want to delete {0} '{1}'?" 
                                    data-md-message-opt-0='<%# Eval("FileType").ToString().Equals("Folder") ? "folder" : "document" %>' data-md-message-opt-1='<%# Eval("Name") %>' 
                                    OnClientClick="return confirmActionModal(this);"><i class="icon-bin"></i>Delete</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <!-- Other Columns-->
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind to register postback on download link

```
protected void bindDownloadAction(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkDownloadBtn = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkDownloadBtn");
    if (lnkDownloadBtn != null)
    {
        ScriptManager mgr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        mgr.RegisterPostBackControl(lnkDownloadBtn);
    }
}
```

I have another update panel in master page with timer as below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNotificationAlertUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="notificationAlertGrid" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate><ul class="media-list dropdown-content-body width-350 pt-0 blockui-alert-notifications ulNotification"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" /></ul></LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li id="Li5" runat="server" class="media alert-notification">
                    <div class="media-left cs-media-mini"><span class="btn border-teal text-teal btn-flat cs-media btn-rounded btn-icon btn-sm"><i class='<%# Eval("NotyTypeIcon") %>'></i></span></div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        ...                                         
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="btnCallIntimationPresentHdn" runat="server" Value="" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCallIntimationNotificationAction" class="btn CallIntimationNotificationAction block-ui-click hidden" data-panel="" runat="server" Text=""
            OnClick="onClickCallIntimationNotification" ValidationGroup="report" data-pid ="" data-entityrefinfo ="" data-uniqueid ="" data-message=""/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RefreshNotificationTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer ID="RefreshNotificationTimer" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="autoRefreshNotifications"></asp:Timer>
```

Problem - When page is loaded first time, download link is working and I am able to download the file. However once timer triggers the tick event, download link does not work and getting below error in browser console.

```
ScriptResource.axd:885 Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
    at Function.Error$create [as create] (ScriptResource.axd:237)
    at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerParserError [as _createPageRequestManagerParserError] (ScriptResource.axd:665)
    at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_parseDelta [as _parseDelta] (ScriptResource.axd:1435)
    at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted [as _onFormSubmitCompleted] (ScriptResource.axd:1314)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd:47)
    at ScriptResource.axd:3484
    at Sys$Net$WebRequest$completed [as completed] (ScriptResource.axd:6376)
    at XMLHttpRequest.Sys$Net$XMLHttpExecutor._onReadyStateChange (ScriptResource.axd:5996)
```

NOTE: When I increase the timer interval to 10 seconds to 5 min then I am able to download file till 5 mins.
As per my understanding partial postback call of timer is removing registered postback controls of other updatepanel from scriptmanager despite updatemode is conditional for both.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet. It finds the GridView of the nested page and rebinds the PostBack trigger on Timer Tick.

```
protected void autoRefreshNotifications(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //find the gridview in the contentplaceholder
    GridView gv = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("folderContentGrid") as GridView;

    //loop all the rows in the gridview
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        //find the linkbutton in the row using findcontrol
        LinkButton lnkDownloadBtn = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("lnkDownloadBtn");

        if (lnkDownloadBtn != null)
        {
            //bind the postback trigger to the linkbutton
            ScriptManager mgr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            mgr.RegisterPostBackControl(lnkDownloadBtn);
        }
    }
}
```

What also works is placing the binding of `folderContentGrid` outside the IsPostBack check. Then RowDataBound is calles on every PostBack. But depending on your requirements and other code that could create some problems as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this is workaround and I have already implemented it(working code) ,inside Page_PreRender method of inner page so that when either partial postback happens it will re-register postback control. But I dont understand why partial postback of timer is removing registered postback controls of another update panel despite they are in updatemode - conditional